# Change value of function or keep it the same with a prototype?

Tags: javascript, function, object, parameters, arguments

How to change value of object if an argument is set and not if one is

example:

```
//parameter is a object
var Main = function(parameter)
{
    this.num = 1;
    this.string = "this"
}

Main.prototype.constructor = Main;

//source is an object
Main.prototype.copy = function(source)
{
    Main.prototype.copy.call(this, source);

    this.num = source.num;
    this.string = source.string;


    return this;
}

//set sub2 to have num is 4 instead of 1
var sub2 = new Main({num:4});
```

and i want to know how to set up a prototype that can allow a change to the original object if an argument is et but use the default from the Main function if an argument isnt set or would i use a function to set the values to default if an argument is empty and then set to the parameter object if it is?

Thanks

Comment: Please show the actual code. `var object = new object…` will always result in a type error.

Comment: that was only an example, the actual code is from three js where you can declare parameters that you want to change for example when creating a  material you can var mat1 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0xffffff});

Comment: So you're asking what the difference between the `color` property of the constructor argument and the `mat1.color` property is?

Comment: Specifically i was asking what type of function can declare an argument that way in order to have properties change for each new object without having to fill in all the arguments

Comment: I know now that it is a prototype with an object as the argument but i don't know how to change the values of an object if a argument is set and not if one isn't

Comment: What is the point of `Main.prototype.constructor = Main;`? That is the default behavior. Why would you write `Main.prototype.copy.call(this, source);` instead of just `this.copy(source)`?

Comment: i realized that wasn't what i was looking for and provided an answer that i was searching for by looking at some source code

Answer (score 2):

The only difference is in nomenclature:

```js
// So if you declare object as
var obj1 = {param1: "value1"};

// there is absolutely no difference if you declare it as
var obj2 = new Object({param2: "value2"});

// Its because every object inherits from Object,
// no matter which way is defined.

// Test
console.log(typeof obj1);
console.log(typeof obj2);

console.log(obj1 instanceof Object);
console.log(obj2 instanceof Object);

// Reaction to your comment below:
// Its as complicated as confusing. In this case 'var obj = {}' you are
// creating object and curly brackets delimit object definition.
// But in this case 'var obj2 = function() {}' you are creating function
// and curly brackets represents 'code block', not object literal.
// But ... function is object also...

var myFunction = function() {};
console.log(myFunction instanceof Object);

// And while this 'var obj = function(){para: 1}' is valid but meaningless 
// code, this 'var obj = function(){this.para: 1}' is as valid as 
// well as frequently used expression to create ... object. But object in 
// another sense... Its really confusing.
```

But first expression, its called "object literal expression", is preferred and safe way to create objects. Because some malicious code can override the Object behaviour. So if you create object as new Object(), you can create something unexpected. But the object literal expresion cant be overrided.

Comment: Ah so this wouldn't work if you declare an object as var obj = function(){para: 1}?

Comment: Sorry did it the wrong way i meant this instead; original: var obj  = {para : 1}; or var obj  = function(); and then creating a new obj: var newObj = new obj({para: 1)};? i am talking about the last one specifically where the parameter can be changed this way, would it be the first obj type or the second one being a function?

Comment: Imagine this code 'var a = 10; var a = 20; console,log(a)'. Console log returns 20. Because in second step you just redefined variable a. So, of course your newObj will be object of second type (function), because in previous statement you just redefined variable obj.

Answer (score 0):

I figureed it out took a while, i decided to look throught the three js code to see how properties were set and I figured out that to set properties i need to go through the object and get the keys and set the keys of the object: here is an example to create planets

```
    /* parameters = {
    radius : <float>
    tilt : <float>
    distance : <float>
    days : <float>
    years : <float>
    diffuse : <texture>
    specular : <texture>
    normal : <texture>
    bump : <texture>
}
*/
var CelestialObject = function (parameters) {
    var toRadians = 180 / Math.PI;

    this.radius = 1;
    this.tilt = 23.5;
    this.distance = 0;
    this.days = 1;
    this.years = 1;
    this.orbitEccentricity = 0;
    this.diffuse = null;
    this.specular = null;
    this.normal = null;
    this.bump = null;


    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();//mesh material
    var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(this.radius, 64, 64);//sphere geometry
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);//mesh

    //Apply Textures
    if (this.diffuse = null)
        material.map = this.diffuse;
    else
        material.color = new THREE.Color(0x777777);
    if (this.specular = null)
        material.map = this.specular;
    if (this.normal = null)
        material.normalMap = this.diffuse;
    if (this.bump = null)
        material.bumpMap = this.bump;

    //Set Tilt
    this.SetTilt = function () {
        mesh.rotateZ(this.tilt * toRadians);
    }

    //Rotate 
    var Rotate = function (mesh) {

        requestAnimationFrame(Rotate);

        var hoursInDay = 24;
        var angle = (360 / (this.days * hoursInDay)) * toRadians;

        mesh.rotateY(angle);
    }

    //Revolve
    var Revolve = function (mesh) {

        requestAnimationFrame(Revolve);

        var time = new Date().getTime();
        var hoursInYears = this.years * 365 * 24;

        time += 360 / hoursInYears;

        var xPos = Math.cos(time) * this.distance;
        var zPos = Math.sin(time) * this.distance * this.orbitEccentricity;


        mesh.position.set(xPos, 0, zPos);
    }

    //set mesh
    this.setMesh = function (customMesh, meshURL) {
        var jsonLoader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
        if (!customMesh)
            mesh = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(this.radius, 64, 64), new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0x777777 }));//sphere
        else
            mesh = jsonLoader.load(meshURL);
    }

    //set values
     for (var key in parameters) {
            var newValue = parameters[key];
            this[key] = newValue;
     }


    Rotate(mesh);
    Revolve(mesh);

    return this;
};
//create new planets here with different values
var earth = new CelestialObject();//use default parameters
var mars = new CelestialObject({radius:.4,tilt:25,distance:141,days:1.5,years:2});//uses new parameters
```

Comment: I do not understand what you mean, what is the purpose of this object Main. Can you write me an example of using of this object?

Comment: example has been updated for what I'm it using it for